# Cannot find com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.dd.VerticalDropLocation

Tags: grails, vaadin, grails-plugin

I'm dooing a Proof of Concept, evaluating Grails (2.1.0) with Vaadin 7 Plugin.
We are evaluating different technologies and the common goal is to have a drag and drop tree set starting from a grails model, change the tree by dragging and drop a child and save the change in the database.

What I need is exactly this, nothing more, nothing less:

http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#DragDropTreeSorting

Unfortunately when i copy and paste the example in a class (i work with IntelliJ 11.13) the IDE complains because it cannot find:

import com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.dd.VerticalDropLocation;

Is this class excluded from the plugin or am i missing something? 
and if yes how do I reproduce the example?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo examples might be in Vaadin 6, but you project is using Vaadin 7 (I would say...). In Vaadin 7 many classes were refactored.

Here is Vaadin 6 [VerticalDropLocation](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/ui/dd/VerticalDropLocation.html)
And here refactored [VerticalDropLocation](https://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.beta1/docs/api/com/vaadin/shared/ui/dd/VerticalDropLocation.html) in Vaadin 7. You can see that they are in different packages... try to import the class from Vaadin 7:

`com.vaadin.shared.ui.dd.VerticalDropLocation`

Comment: ok that worked. In the ExampleUtil.java i also had to change the import for ThemeResource and Resource.

Now I have a problem while starting the application (javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: app.DragDropTreeSortingExample does not implement UI) but i believe that from now on i should really read the documentation ;)

thanks!

Comment: if that helped, mark the question as answered. and report the other issue in separate question with all the needed details